# Use PDF.js viewer on part of page

Tags: javascript, pdf, mozilla, pdf.js

How can I use the standard viewer UI of PDF.js for rendering a PDF in a website where the document viewer only takes up part of the page (like the [hello world](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/helloworld.html) example)? 
Which properties should I pass to the viewer, and which method do I need to call  in the loading script?

I have tried installing the viewer locally and showing the PDF in an `iframe` with that viewer, passing the filename as URL parameter, but that aborts the pageload before it finishes.

I haven't been able to find any examples of this, and looking through the code itself does not help me much. What am I missing?!

**EDIT:** I ended up using the iframe-solution, which actually works very well, I just made a embarrasing mistake in the load of the iframe.

Comment: are you looking for `iframe` tag?

Comment: @syedfaizan: I don't understand your question. I already use the `iframe` tag to load the viewer as part of my page. Is that what you mean?